# Creating an image handler in Visual Basic for Ajax file upload

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm not asking for detailed code for this question, but rather solid direction to learn how to do it myself. There appears to be many methods and directions so just looking for a headstart from someone experienced.

I have a simple file upload control. I want it to operate as an ajax upload, no page-refresh, and if I'm understanding correctly I need http handler that grabs the image and deals with it behind the scenes.

So I need to create a custom control, a new file upload that allows me to set some properties, such as... Path for the image, prefix for three different types (I.e. thm_uniqueimagename.jpg, med_uniqueimagename.jpg, lg_uniqueimagename.jpg) and an option to either KeepOriginal="True/False".

I'd like to see a progress bar while the image is uploading as well. A fantastic example would be a post on Facebook and how you can upload an image.

Right now I'm stuck with a standard upload control that has full post-back/refresh and it's just not nearly as attractive.

I'm just now learning VB... So basically if you can say... Read this tutorial, then do this, then do this... that would be greatly helpful. Just overwhelmed with what to do first, and how to put it all together.

Platform: Windows, .net, etc.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a better user experience, then I suggest you investigate some solutions like the following:

1. ASP.NET AJAX file upload

   [AjaxFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ajaxFileUpload/ajaxFileUpload.aspx).

   Note: If you read the documentation for the ASP.NET AJAX AjaxFileUploader, it says that it requires HTML5 for the progress feedback; otherwise it shows a spinner. So if progress feedback is a necessity and you cannot fully support HTML5 in your target browsers (i.e. older versions of IE; IE6, IE7, IE8, etc.), then you should look into the options below.
2. Custom HTTP module

   [NeatUpload](http://neatupload.codeplex.com/) is a free option.
3. Silverlight/Flash option

   [SWFUpload](https://code.google.com/p/swfupload/) is a free option.
4. Asynchronous chunking option

   [RadAsyncUpload - Telerik's ASP.NET AsyncUpload](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) is a pay option, check website for pricing.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking into option 1. I actually need to build this as a custom asp.net control to work with an application layer. I've referenced the ajaxtoolkit dll, and used inherit on the ajaxfileupload, but it's telling me things like, 'nameofcontrol' doesn't have a public property 'backcolor" and other properties that are in the original control. The problem is, I can't figure out how to write the properties in VB, and I thought inheriting the ajaxfileupload would do the trick.. but I'm new at this. Any suggestions? Thank you!